# Easily reproduced total loss of power in a handful of specific situations - ideas?

Tags: power-supply, power, gpu, cooling, overheating

I've recently assembled a new desktop machine from mostly new parts, plus a handful of still-working parts from my old build. For the most part it's running great, HOWEVER - I have an odd power-related goblin that crops up in a very small number of reliably-reproducible circumstances.

In SOME (not all) situations where the GPU is about to start doing something more intense (i.e. in a game, a level has just loaded and the GPU is about to render it), right before it starts, the entire machine will lose power and cut off - no throttling, no weird behavior or errors or anything, just a complete fans-cut-off, lights-go-out shutdown. The power button won't respond until I switch the PSU off/on.

Some observations:

--this has only happened in two situations: one time (cannot reproduce) when loading a new game in Kerbal Space Program, right before the space center renders, and EVERY TIME I attempt to load a saved game in the new BattleTech (after everything has loaded from disk but right before the level is rendered.)

--CPU is brand spanking new and peaks at about 60 under heavy load.

--my GPU is a few years old and runs a bit hot, but not to a worrying degree (Afterburner says it peaks at about 82 under heavy load... hot, but not to the point of throttling and definitely not close to shutdown.)

--most other components are new (and I've double checked that everyone is seated well and all the connections are good), except for

--my PSU, which is a dinosaur from my old build. It's rated at 700 watts, which is supposedly plenty of overhead, but I am highly suspicious of it.

Based on the above, I'm reticent to blame my GPU since it can do a lot of other graphically intense stuff (like Fallout 4 with a ton of graphical mods) and ramp all the way up to its peak temperature without complaining about it.  I'm also not ready to blame memory or CPU, as it seems to me like if that was the case this would be manifesting in more places.  I read somewhere that the weirder the problem, the more likely it's a PSU issue, and in this case I kind of agree - my hunch is that in some situations, the GPU requests an amount of power that the PSU isn't able to handle anymore, so the PSU panics and shuts down the party.

I'm probably going to replace the PSU in the short term anyway, since it's the oldest thing in this machine... fortunately it's not misbehaving in any other ways but I'd prefer not to take the chance of it failing completely and taking other things with it. I'm probably also going to set up my GPU with a better cooling solution soon, just to make sure that doesn't become a bigger problem. But if there's anything else I may be missing, or some other diagnostics I should do first, I'd like to hear yall's thoughts.

Specs are as follows (happy to provide more info if needed):

--mobo: MSI B350 Tomahawk Plus (a few weeks old)

--CPU: Ryzen 5 1600x, cooled by a MasterLiquid 120, running at stock speed (a few weeks old)

--memory: 2x8gb Ballistix Sport DDR4 (a few weeks old)

--GPU: ASUS Strix R9 380x, stock cooler, running at stock speed (about three years old)

--PSU: Some 700w Rosewill fossil (about nine years old)

Thanks all ^^

EDIT

On @DigitalLightcraft's advice I installed and attempted to run Furmark for a more reliable test.  Having set the temperature alarm at 90 degrees, I attempted to run the 1080p burn-in test (not XTreme) - upon clicking 'GO', my machine instantly cut off, exactly as described above.  No strange behavior beforehand, or any period of time to build up heat - just an instant shutdown.

Some new behavior, as well.  Where Fallout 4 was working happily as of yesterday evening, it now triggers the same shutdown as soon as the heavy rendering starts (the 3D models on the loading screens are apparently fine, but the actual game world now triggers the shutdown.)  Whatever the problematic component is, it appears to be getting worse.  I'm thinking it would probably be wise to keep the desktop shut down for the time being until I replace the problematic component.

Comment: You should only need around 500W for that setup, but if your PSU is that old, the capacitors, etc could be showing their age causing the PSU to trip off.  Can you see into the PSU?  Is it dusty?  Do any of the capacitors look like they are leaking or the top is bulging?

Comment: Have you tried running a GPU stress test program?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft, I actually have not. Probably should. Any recommendations?

Comment: @essjae, I can -kind of- see into the PSU... the windows are pretty cloudy on the inside these days. I don't see any obvious physical issues with the capacitors but that just might mean it's obscured. Highly likely that it's dust city in there though. I'll probably take a closer look this evening.

Comment: @DoctorAxel - FurMark is good

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft thanks, I'll give it a try this evening.  Results forthcoming.

Comment: @essjae, having taken a closer look, I can confirm that it's SUPER dusty in there - cleaned it out with some compressed air but that only goes so far.  I don't see anything outright damaged or scorched in there, though.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft - installed Furmark, and set it up to run a regular (not XTreme) burn-in test at 1080p with the alarm set at 90 degrees.  Upon clicking GO, my machine instantly cut off - exact same issue as described above.  No weird behavior beforehand, just an instant shutdown.  Reproduced exactly when I attempted it a second and third time.  Very interesting!

After powering back up, I launched my heavily modded Fallout 4 to make sure that was still behaving as expected, and it is - no shutoff, GPU runs between 75 and 80 degrees without complaint.

Any thoughts on that result?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft - I take it back! Having fired up Fallout 4 a moment ago, I experienced the very same shutoff issue the moment the game was about to render - the 3D models shown during the loading screens were fine, but the actual game environment is now triggering a shutdown.  This is new behavior.  Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the weekend I set myself up with a new EVGA 850 G3... obviously a LOT of overhead based on what my build needs, but I got it on sale and it was actually cheaper than the equivalent 650 at the time, so I figured I may as well.  This appears to have solved my power loss issues - neither Battletech, nor Fallout, nor Furmark or anything else I've tried out will trigger the shutoff anymore. A few days later and everything is still running quite happily.

After pulling out the old PSU, I did see what I think is some SLIGHT deformation on a couple of capacitors - easy to miss while it was still installed in the tower. So it looks like this was just a case of a gradual, relatively gentle PSU failure.

Side note, modular PSU's are wonderful when you've been dealing with the old Kraken-tentacle-style PSU's for the last nine years.

Thanks for the guidance, all ^^

Comment: I went with a modular PSU for my most recent build, and I don't think I can ever go back now.